# Odoo10 : How can I automatically get the value for partner when customer number is given?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-10

I am creating a module something like call log.  In that i need to search the customer number and get the Partner information or have to link the partner automatically.

the following are the codes, somebody please help me.

```
class model_call(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _name = 'model.call'
    _description = 'call logs'

    """ *************** Base Fields ******************* """
    name = fields.Char(string='Topic')
    customer_number = fields.Char(string='Customer Number', track_visiility='onchange', onchange='get_partner(customer_number)')
#-------------------------------------------------
#       apis
#-------------------------------------------------

    @api.onchange('customer_number')
    def get_partner(self, customer_number):
         if customer_number:
            customer = self.env['res.partner'].search([('customer_number', '=', record.phone)])

            return customer
#------------------------------------------------------

    customer = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Customer', track_visibility='onchange',index=True, help="Linked partner (optional). Usually created when converting the lead.",)
```

Comment: Why do you inherit `res.partner`?

Comment: In onchange fnct, you have not to add parmater

Comment: And your oncange methode is all wrong

Comment: to get the fields in res.partner, we have to compare the phone or mobile fields from res.partner for getting the partner. so i need to inherit it right??

Answer (score 0):

Your onchange isn't correct. You don't need parameters and have to return a dictionary or nothing. The dictionary is only needed for field filtering changes and warning messages. Value changes like yours are made "directly":

```py
@api.onchange('customer_number')
def get_partner(self):
     if self.customer_number:
        customer = self.env['res.partner'].search(
            [('customer_number', '=', self.phone)])  # shouldn't it be self.customer_number?
        self.customer = customer
```

And try to stick to the [Odoo Guidelines](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/guidelines.html) and change the field `customer` to `customer_id`.

Comment: You will get a NameError Exception `global name 'record' is not defined`.

Comment: Oops, yep `record` is never declared. I will edit my answer